# What's meant by fluids 'clamping' to something?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations

Apparently aerogel clamps fluids particularly strongly. What does that mean? And what property of a material makes a fluid 'clamp' to it? I've seen the term [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921452699020748) in the abstract, and in a few similar papers. A brief explanation in a paper or textbook would be ideal, but I can't find anything. Seems to be a low temperature term mainly, the most important thing I need is to know why a aerogel would 'clamp' fluid particularly strongly.

Comment: You could add resources recommended tag if you cannot find anything on the web , especially if you are looking for a lot of background,  not just a quick definition.

Comment: -1. Please provide some link or quotation. Where have you seen this term used? What research have you done already to find an answer?

Comment: @sammygerbil Apologies, I've never used this tag before, added a little more to the question. As to the research I've done - I've typed various search terms into google and only really come up with the original links I saw the term in. Seems to be a low temp thing. I have a rough idea of what it means, I think it possibly relates to viscous penetration depth, but no idea why aerogel might clamp particularly strongly.